# Image being requested multiple times on RadListView

Tags: nativescript

I'm loading a list of items, each with an URL reference for a thumbnail foreach item. When rendering the list using RadListView, I notice that each image is being loaded several times from the server. This only happens in iOS, in Android each thumbnail only loads once. The view however, is correct (no duplicates).

NativeScript version is 5.1.1

```
<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar id="searchBar" hint="{{sbHint}}" text="{{sbText}}" clear="onClear" submit="onSubmit" />
    <GridLayout rows="auto, *" class="list-group">
        <lv:RadListView class="listview" items="{{itemList}}" pullToRefresh="true" pullToRefreshInitiated="onPullToRefreshInitiated" loaded="onListLoaded" itemTemplateSelector="selectItemTemplate" row="1">
            <lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>
                <template key="hasimg">
                    <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="70,*,auto" class="list-group-item" tap="select">
                        <Image row="0" col="0" src="{{imgurl}}" width="60" height="50" stretch="aspectFill"/>
                        <Label  row="0" col="1" class="p-l-15 text" text="{{ name }}"/>
                        <Label class="p-l-15 fa" text="&#xf054;" row="0" col="2"/>
                    </GridLayout>
                </template>
                <template key="noimg">
                    <GridLayout rows="auto" columns="70,*,auto" class="list-group-item" tap="select">
                        <Label class="fa imgicon" text="&#xf1b2;" row="0" col="0"/>
                        <Label  row="0" col="1" class="p-l-15 text" text="{{ name }}"/>
                        <Label class="p-l-15 fa" text="&#xf054;" row="0" col="2"/>
                    </GridLayout>
                </template>
            </lv:RadListView.itemTemplates>
        </lv:RadListView>
        <ActivityIndicator busy="{{ isLoading }}" row="1" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"/>
    </GridLayout>
</StackLayout>
```

Output from the API server on the same list load, using iOS and Android.

Using iOS (wrong):

GET  /v4/item/file/display/1/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/1/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/2/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/2/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/1/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/2/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/1/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/2/  404 Not Found
POST /v4/item/list/            200 OK

Using Android (correct):

GET  /v4/item/file/display/1/  404 Not Found
GET  /v4/item/file/display/2/  404 Not Found
POST /v4/item/list/            200 OK

(in reversed order, please ignore the 404, I changed the path better to diff each call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using ListView, it reuses the item template as you scroll down / up. Let's say if you have 100 data items loaded on ListView, it would not create 100 View / Image components. It will probably create a few depending on the visible area of your screen, when you scroll up / down the same views will be reused for other data items to keep the performance up. This is the advantage of using ListView or RadListView.

Coming to why the Image was loaded multiple times, by default Android caches the image and uses it on subsequent requests. With iOS, it doesn't. So it hits the URL every time whenever it has to render the image while you scroll up / down.

The solution is to cache your images in temp storage. You could simply do it with http module and a bit of logical statements Or there are even several plugins you could find in the market place for this purpose, `nativescript-web-image-cache` or `nativescript-image-cache-it` are couple to name.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'll try the caching method then :)